# Add [DataObject] to exsisting array with var key

Tags: javascript, arrays

Using Cordova, I am trying to get an Object to add to an array.  I have this working on node JS using :
`theData = {[varkey]:DataObject};`

But I can't get this to work the same way within my javascript that cordova runs.

I need to do the following:

```
var TownName = 'Auckland', var townData = (JSON Data);
theArray = new Array();

theArray[TownName] = townData;
```

I need to be able to call it back as:

```
theArray['Auckland']
```

Which will return (JSON Data)

But it doesn't want to store the data with the key inside the array.

I have also tried:

```
theArray.TownName = townData;
theArray = [{TownName:townData}];
theArray = {[TownName]:townData}];
```

Nothing wants to store the data.

Any suggestions?

::EDIT::

```
data.theData = 
"Auckland"[  
   {  
      "username":"pndemoname1",
      "number":"373456",
      "www":"http://373456.pndemoname1",
      "icon":"/imgs/pndemoname1.png"
   },
   {  
      "username":"pndemoname2",
      "number":"373458",
      "www":"http://373458.pndemoname2",
      "icon":"/imgs/pndemoname2.png"
   }

data.town = "Auckland";

townData = new Array();

alert(JSON.stringify(data.theData))//Alerts theData

townData[data.town] = data.theData

alert(townData[townName]) //Alerts undefined
```

::EDIT2::

Re-defining the array within the function that deals with all of the data, seems to make it work.

As per my answer, the issue was that I assumed javascript vars are global.

Comment: Why do you want to use an `array` to hold key value pairs, which need not be indexed? You could simply use an `Object`.

Comment: More towns will be added, I am using one as an example.  At the end it will all be stored to be retrieved later, and Arrays will make the job easier to storage instead of having a ton of objects stored

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something, but this works:
https://jsfiddle.net/yhmn8mwm/

Comment: Is `JSON Data` the same thing as `theData` in your question?

Comment: Json Data is the var of townData

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider, You would think this would work, but in the project, it does not.

Comment: Can you post a complete example? Something must be missing.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider Added

Answer (score 0):

Use objects or an array of objects.

A data structure like this:

```
{
    town1: town1Data,
    town2: town2Data,
}
```

Or more common:

```
[
    {
        name: "Town 1",
        data: {...}
    },
    {
        name: "Town 2",
        data: {...}
    },
]
```

For reference:

http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 0):

I got what you're trying to do, to add property names dynamically to your object is first, by making sure you are using an OBJECT instead of an array, so when you want to store something you will do the following:

```
var _obj = {}, _something = 'xyz';
_obj[ _something ] = {  ...  }; // json structure
```

The problem you're facing is that you want to assign a string value as a key inside your array, which will not work.

However, you can still use the array you defined and do the following:

```
var _array = new array();
_array.push( { .... } ); // insert json structure
```

Remember! By using the array you will have to loop through all values every time you want to access your key, just as the best practice to avoid getting into errors.

Good luck.

Comment: Arrays are only meant for numerical storage. Strings will assign property names for the array, but that will not be accessible if you want to loop through it, which defeats the whole purpose. Look at: http://tinyurl.com/zp73dns

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I didn't define the array within the function of where I was trying to add the information to.

I assumed the var was global (Too much PHP)